# Nested API : ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to test my API with RSpec.

Api::V1::EventsController exists and has a create method. I use simple_token_authentication and pundit for security.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      # users/
      resources :users, only: [:show, :update] do
        # users/:id/events/
        resources :events
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Spec :

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::EventsController, type: :controller do

  describe 'events#create' do
    before {
      @user = User.create(email: 'm@m.fr', password: '12345678', password_confirmation: '12345678')
      @user.reload
    }

    it 'should 401 if bad credentials' do
      # Given the user

      # When
      post "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}/events", {},
      {
        'x-user-email' => 'toto',
        'x-user-token' => 'toto'
      }

      # Then
      expect_status 401
    end
  end
end
```

And i get this error :

```
   Failure/Error: post "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}/events", {},
   ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
     No route matches {:action=>"/api/v1/users/1/events", :controller=>"api/v1/events"}
```

EDIT and answer :
I was confused and i was using rspec controller when i wanted to use rspec request.
Here's my working example :

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::EventsController, type: :controller do

  describe 'events#create' do
    before {
      @user = User.create(email: 'm@m.fr', password: '12345678', password_confirmation: '12345678')
      @user.reload
    }

    it 'should 401 if bad credentials' do
      # Given the user

      # When
      post "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}/events", {}.to_json,
      {
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'x-user-email' => 'toto',
        'x-user-token' => 'toto'
      }

      # Then
      expect_status 401
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: run rake routes to see what existing routes are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `post` method in a controller spec takes an action name for the first parameter, not a path, so instead of:

```
post "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}/events", #...
```

try:

```
post :create, #...
```

Controller specs are unit tests. If you want to test the entire stack, use a [feature spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) instead of a controller spec.

Comment: thanks. i didn't understand controller tests were unit tests. I'm using request tests now, and it works.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do the request with the full path, because you already testing the Api::V1::EventsController.

So it will be much better to use special syntax for it:

```
post :create, nil, {
  'x-user-email' => 'toto',
  'x-user-token' => 'toto'
}

expect(response.response_code).to eq 401
```

If you want to test the route, you should do it in the routes specs:

```
# spec/routing/api_v1_events_routing_spec.rb
require "spec_helper"

RSpec.describe Api::V1::EventsController do
  describe "routing" do
    it "#create" do
      expect(post: "/api/v1/users/1/events").to \
        route_to(controller: "api/v1/events", action: "create", user_id: "1") 
    end
  end 
end
```